# How to generate primary key using other fields in django models

Tags: django, django-models

I a trying to generate a primary key using the other fields of the model.

```
unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, primary_key=True)
restaurant_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
manager_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
mobile_no = models.CharField(unique=True, validators=[validate_mobile], max_length=10)
state = models.CharField(choices=STATES, max_length=2)
city = models.CharField(max_length=20)
pincode = models.CharField(max_length=8, validators=[validate_pincode])
street_address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
password = models.CharField(max_length=256)
```

Comment: can you explain more your question?

Comment: i want to override the auto_primary_key of django and instead create a unique id of 10 letters using some algo.
I am saving the model using modelForm btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of the `default` field option.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#default

Just like how it's done on `UUIDField`.

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#uuidfield

Then I'm guessing just try to assign your algo each and every time on your `unique_id`